# Php get from array

Tags: php

I have small problem, I can't get info from an array.
This is outcome when I var_dump variable.

```
array(1) { 
  ["server"]=> array(34) { 
     ["dedicated"]=> string(1) "d"
     ["game_descr"]=> string(14) "Counter-Strike"
     ["game_dir"]=> string(7) "cstrike"
     ["gq_address"]=> string(13) "185.119.89.91"
     ["gq_dedicated"]=> string(1) "d"
     ["gq_gametype"]=> string(14) "Counter-Strike"
     ["gq_hostname"]=> string(26) "Assassin'S CSDM [de_dust2]"
     ["gq_joinlink"]=> string(36) "steam://connect/185.119.89.91:27031/"
     ["gq_mapname"]=> string(8) "de_dust2"
     ["gq_maxplayers"]=> int(32)
     ["gq_mod"]=> string(7) "cstrike"
     ["gq_name"]=> string(18) "Counter-Strike 1.6"
     ["gq_numplayers"]=> int(32) 
     ["gq_online"]=> bool(true) 
     ["gq_password"]=> int(0)
     ["gq_port_client"]=> int(27031)
     ["gq_port_query"]=> int(27031)
     ["gq_protocol"]=> string(6) "source"
     ["gq_transport"]=> string(3) "udp"
     ["gq_type"]=> string(4) "cs16"
     ["hostname"]=> string(26) "Assassin'S CSDM [de_dust2]"
     ["map"]=> string(8) "de_dust2"
     ["max_players"]=> int(32)
     ["num_bots"]=> int(0)
     ["num_players"]=> int(32)
     ["os"]=> string(1) "l"
     ["password"]=> int(0)
     ["players"]=> array(0) { }
     ["port"]=> int(27031)
     ["protocol"]=> int(48)
     ["secure"]=> int(1)
     ["steamappid"]=> int(10)
     ["teams"]=> array(0) { }
     ["version"]=> string(13) "1.1.2.7/Stdio"
   }
 }
```

How to get hostname for example?
I tried like `$info['hostname']`, `$info[0]['hostname'];` But nothing works, why?

Comment: Please share your attempts. It's pretty obvious that you have missed an array key

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> array(1) { ... }
> ```

The array has one thing in it.

> ```
> ["server"]=> array(34) { ... }
> ```

… which is another array with 34 things in it.

---

You are ignoring the outer array. You need to get the inner array and then access the item you want from that.

```
$info['server']['hostname']
```